# How do I know when a Knockout component has finished updating the DOM?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, dom-events, knockout-3.0

How do I know when a Knockout component has finished updating the DOM?  Is there a callback or some other facility when a component has finished updating or writing it's template into the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157350/knockoutjs-afterrender-callback-when-all-nested-components-have-been-rendered)

Comment: Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/a/26702397/392102

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KnockoutJS afterRender callback when all nested Components have been rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157350/knockoutjs-afterrender-callback-when-all-nested-components-have-been-rendered)